# OpenCV crashes randomly in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

The following codes crashes silently while execution for large vectors `rand_values`:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as opencv2

rand_values = np.random.random(size=int(1E7)).astype('float32')

for i in range(0, int(1e7)):
    smoothed_values = opencv2.bilateralFilter(
                    rand_values,
                    5,
                    0.3,
                    5.0
                )
    print(f"{i:04} Smoothing done")
```

If `rand_values` has up to ~10<sup>3</sup> elements, all loops are executed correctly (tested with 10<sup>7</sup> loop iterations). With increasing vector size, the program crashes silently during execution of `opencv2.bilateralFilter(...)` without any log or trace message. The python process is killed completely.

For sizes of ~10<sup>5</sup> elements, the program crashes after 5 to 10 loop iterations (number of correctly executed loops differs randomly between different runs). For a vector size of 10<sup>7</sup> elements, the program crashes most times at 2nd loop iteration. The first loop iteration always succeeds independent of the vector's size (tested for vector size of 10<sup>9</sup> elements and 10 runs).

If the bilateralFilter-method is moved to a second process by using multiprocessing, the program never crashes independent of vector size or number of loop iterations:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from multiprocessing import Process

def do_smooth(index: int):

    rand_values = np.random.randint(2, size=int(1E5))

    smoothed_values = cv2.bilateralFilter(
                    rand_values.astype('float32'),
                    5,
                    0.3,
                    5
                )
    print(f"{index:04} Subprocess done")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(0, int(1e2)):
        p = Process(target=do_smooth, args=(i,))
        p.start()
        p.join()
        print(f'{i:04} done')
```

The program is executed in an anaconda environment with python 3.9.6 (conda-forge) and openCV 4.5.2 (conda-forge) running on Windows 10. The tests were repeated on a second Windows 10 machine and the same results were reproduced.

Had anyone similar issues? Any help to solve the issue is very much appreciated!

#### This is what I have tried, to solve the problem

##### Using Debugger

Running the code in python debugger, has the same result as normal execution (and still no trace back or other logging output)

##### Deleting Variables

I've tried to move `random_values` inside the for-loop and calling `del smoothed_elements` and `del rand_values` at the end of each loop iteration.

##### Reload openCV

I've tried to reload the openCV module at the beginning of each loop iteration by use of 'importlib.reload(...)'

Comment: Looks like a bug in OpenCV... `bilateralFilter` expects an image (2D array) and not a vector (1D array). For example: `rand_values = np.random.random((4000, 4000)).astype('float32')` works. In case you really want to find the bug in OpenCV, you have to debug OpenCV C++ source code. You may need to build OpenCV from sources in Debug configuration...

Answer (score 0):

@Rotem's comment actually solved my issue. This code runs without any problems (tested with cycle of 100 iterations):

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as opencv2

rand_values = np.random.randint(2, size=(int(1E8))).astype('float32')
fake_img = np.array([rand_values, rand_values])

for i in range(0, int(1e3)):

    smoothed_values = opencv2.bilateralFilter(
                    fake_img,
                    5,
                    0.3,
                    5.0
                )[0]
    # print(smoothed_values)
    print(f"{i:04} Smoothing done")
```